# What is a simple way to prepend a UTF-8 character to a text file using cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, utf-8

Something like:

```
echo \ufeff > output.csv
type input.csv >> output.csv
```

Where `\ufeff` is the UTF-8 BOM, and `input.csv` is a UTF-8 text file.

How do I indicate a UTF-8 character in cmd?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500 helps you. And later, when you have the character in `file1`, do `copy file1+file2 newfile`.

Comment: Thanks. How do I actually indicate \ufeff in the command line though?

Comment: Another link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962172/echo-utf-8-characters-in-windows-batch but it uses not the standard `echo`. Do you want to insert a BOM into a file?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to use `Notepad++` for this. Go to `Encoding` and set `Encode in UTF-8`, that will set a BOM.

Comment: @ott I'm trying to do this on the command line :)

Comment: To create a template with just a BOM in it.

Comment: k i created bom.csv as an empty file with UTF-8 encoding (w bom), then append the real csv to it and it works. Can it be done without the extra file though?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @ott for the tips. Here's how to do it:

Use Notepad++ with the TextFX plugin

Create a batch file `addbom.bat` in Notepad++, then Main Menu > Encoding > Encode in UTF-8 without BOM

Enter the following:

```
@echo off

set "BOM=EF BB BF"
<nul set /p = %BOM%> output.csv
type %1 >> output.csv
```

Hightlight `EF BB BF` then Main Menu > TextFX > TextFX Convert > Convert Hex to Text. This changes the text to:

```
@echo off

set "BOM="
<nul set /p = %BOM%> output.csv
type %1 >> output.csv
```

Save the file, then in the command prompt run `addbom bad.csv`. Your BOM'd csv will be in `output.csv`

`<nul set /p=` is the same as `echo` but doesn't produce a newline

Comment: Excellent! This can be made a bit more dynamic by replacing output.csv with for example `%~n1-bom.csv`. This appends `-bom` to the original filename. This avoids accidentally overwriting the output file as well.